# how to return boolean in order to conditionally format a cell?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

The following code in VBE should return true, so that when invoked from the Conditional Format dialog the cell is modified accordingly:

```
Function sshProblem()
   Dim portStatus As String
    portStatus = ActiveCell.Value
    If StrComp(portStatus, "No") = 0 Then
       sshProblem = True
    End If
End Function
```

If I apply this conditional settings to a cell with the value "No", nothing happens:

[image]

Comment: You should also probably add `As Boolean` after your function declaration.

Comment: you can replace `ActiveCell.Value` with `Application.Caller` but please don't use VBA when there is absolutely no need for it :[ Also, any numeric value that does not evaluate to zero or error will be considered as True

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass the range into the function and not use active cell as that changes every time you change the selection:

```
Function sshProblem(rng As Range) As Boolean
   Dim portStatus As String
    portStatus = rng.Value
    If StrComp(portStatus, "No") = 0 Then
       sshProblem = True
    End If
End Function
```

Then you would call it using the upper left cell in the range over which you are formatting.

So if I was formatting A1:A1000 the formula would be:

```
=sshProblem(A1)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

But as @Mat'sMug, in his infinite wisdom, stated this can be done with a simple existing formula:

```
=A1="No"
```

No vba needed for something simple.

Comment: Also declaring an explicit return type on the function signature wouldn't hurt either - `Public Function SshProblem(rng As Range) As Boolean`; that way it returns `False` instead of `Variant/Empty` and making Excel convert *that* to a Boolean value after returning. I'd argue that the function is superfluous though, the VBA code isn't doing anything that can't be done with a simple Excel formula.

Comment: @Mat'sMug I thought the same and just assumed that the OP was using this as a learning experience.  Add a note to echo your statement.

Comment: The function could also be simplified to `Function sshProblem(rng As Range) As Boolean` `sshProblem = StrComp(rng.Value, "No") = 0` `End Function`

Comment: @YowE3K It surely can.  I wanted to give the guidance, assuming that the OP was doing this not as a end but as a learning experience.  So I simply fixed what was wrong.  But that is very concise, and I like it a lot.

Comment: I just couldn't pass up the opportunity to complain about the use of a logical expression to test whether to set a logical variable to a logical constant with the same value as the logical expression.  (Especially when the code was so "sloppy" that it didn't handle the "False" part of the expression ;-) )  (P.S. Just in case it's not obvious - I'm just joking about the "sloppy" coding part!!!  Well, it was no more than a **friendly** dig anyway.)

Comment: @YowE3K I have had this discussion with Mat'sMug before.  I will answer the question and fix glaring mistakes, but I will leave it to the OP to go to CodeReview to get the pointers on how to make it faster and/or simpler.  I break this rule on occasion when I feel lazy.  Today was not one of those days.

Comment: Perfectly acceptable practice - and I usually **try** to do that too.  (Except my attempts to stick to that rule usually fail because I tend to get excited about the chance to do some coding and end up changing the OP's code despite my attempts not to.)

Comment: Thanks to all. You are all right. The code as it is is probably futile. BUT, yes, it is part of my VBA learning curve (I'm more used to javascript), and besides, this is just the beginning. The function should get more complicated in time. I need to evaluate not only if the cell value says "No", but also if the value from another cell inthe row contains certain device type. Then format the cell range.

Comment: I just realize: Scott's code works very well, now, if I apply it to a range such as $I:$I it doesnt format the range, if I use =$I$6:$I$8 it then works. I have other rules applied to ranges such as $K:$K that are working fine. Any ideas?

Comment: @JoseMendez It will work just fine if it is applied to the whole column you just need to use the upper left cell as the reference.  so `=sshProblem(J1)`  You do not want to put the full column or full range reference in the formula.  That is what the `Applies To:` box is for.